# Implement 'rescue' without 'next'

Tags: ruby

I have this example to handle errors and continue code execution:

```
begin
  p '-' * 100
  request_builder.new(env: tested_env).submit!
rescue => error
  error_logs << "#{error}\n#{error.backtrace.first(5).join("\n")}"
  next
end
```

How can I rewrite the code without `next`?

I found this example:

```
%w(1 2).each do |x|
  p x
  begin
    raise 'something'
  rescue => error
    p error
  end
end
=>
"1"
#<RuntimeError: something>
"2"
#<RuntimeError: something>
```

How can it be used to implement the code?

Comment: Not certain I understand the initial code since `next` in the given context will raise a `SyntaxError` since there is no loop. Can you please provide a complete example of the current code

Comment: Removing `next` should work.

Comment: Yes, but I want when I have exception to continue with the rest of the code.

Comment: Removing `next` IS the answer. If you have a rescue block, the application will just continue there.

Answer (score 0):

The next in you example has nothing to do, with a normal rescue block. It just tells to go to the next iteration. So remove your next statement and you are find.

```
begin
  p '-' * 100
  request_builder.new(env: tested_env).submit!
rescue => error
  error_logs << "#{error}\n#{error.backtrace.first(5).join("\n")}"
  # next # removing next, removes you error, 
         # you just put whatever you want in your rescue block, 
         # the application continues in this block
end
```